# Redux-Toolkit and React Hooks - Store change does not trigger re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pre-populate a form with information from the database whenever the URL contains a query parameter with an ID. I am unable to make the site trigger a re-render when the information is fetched from the database. The relevant code in the component is shown below.

```js
let { id } = useParams();

const { title, summary, severity, references, type, vulnerabilities } = useSelector(
        (state: RootState) => state.articles.article
)

useEffect(() => {
    if(id) dispatch(fetchArticle(id))
}, [])

const [form, setForm] = useState<FormState>({
    title: title,
    type: type,
    summary: summary,
    severity: severity,
    references: references,
    vulnerabilities: vulnerabilities,
    autocompleteOptions: autocompleteSuggestions,
    reference: "",
    vulnerability: "",
})

useEffect(() => { 
    setForm({
        ...form,
        title: title,
        summary: summary,
        severity: severity,
        references: references,
        type: type,
        vulnerabilities: vulnerabilities
    })
}, [title, summary, severity, references, type, vulnerabilities])
```

[image]

We can see that the Redux action is fired and the article state is updated in the store. I have also tried to `console.log` inside the hook to verify that it runs, which it does, but only on the initial render. If I change `initialState` in the slice, then it is reflected in the form.

```js
let initialState: ArticleState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    article: {
        title: "",
        severity: 0,
        type: 0,
        summary: "",
        references: [],
        vulnerabilities: [],
        id: 0
    },
    articles: [] as Article[],
    autocompleteSuggestions: [] as DropdownItem[]
}

const ArticleSlice = createSlice({
    name: "articles",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getArticleStart: startLoading,
        getArticleFailure: loadingFailed,

        getArticleSuccess(state: ArticleState, { payload }: PayloadAction<Article>) {
            state.article = payload
            state.error = null
            state.loading = false
        }
    }
})

export const {
    getArticleFailure,
    getArticleStart,
    getArticleSuccess
} = ArticleSlice.actions

export default ArticleSlice.reducer
```

Weirdly enough, if I save the code while on the page the hot-reloading *does* update it and triggers a re-render, populating the form correctly.

Note that I am using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), hence the slice syntax.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not promising anything but try this, see if it works:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
    if (id) dispatch(fetchArticle(id));
    await setForm({
      ...form,
      title: title,
      summary: summary,
      severity: severity,
      references: references,
      type: type,
      vulnerabilities: vulnerabilities
    })
  })();
}, []);
```

Then remove the second useEffect. If this doesn't work, can we see your render jsx code?